# How can I make my google cardboard VR/AR application work for both Google Cardboard and Google Glass?

Tags: android, google-glass, augmented-reality, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have developed an android application for Google cardboard which uses cardboard library. Now, I want to get it worked for both Google glass and Google cardboard.

As soon as i launch application, it should detect the device and work accordingly.

Please Help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You might define and use this function to determine if your code is running on Google Glass

```
boolean isRunningOnGlass() {
     return "Google".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER) && Build.MODEL.startsWith("Glass");
 }
```